# What do all these updates do?

Tags: updates

I am new to Ubuntu and anything Linux based.

I'm getting pop ups almost every day telling me of important updates I have to/can install, and am wondering what these updates that come out so regularly actually do?

Is their purpose to improve the user experience in the sense of adding features (ie making the OS more cluttered) or actually improving performance? If they are simply adding features, I would rather turn them off.

Now I know there are different types of updates, the security updates are self explanatory, I am however talking about the  "recommended updates".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security updates are obviously the ones you need in order to keep you system secure.

Recommended Updates and other usually contain non-critical updates which fix some bugs in the program or some broken package etc... and do not affect the security of the system. They generally improve the system stability in various ways.

You can expand the technical description tab within the update panel, select the specific update and see what the update entails, then you can choose to update or not.

See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuUpdates) for further reference.